# The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller? please

Tags: php, css, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
**DefaultController.php**
```

This is my DefaultController.php file i am going to simple login page in symfony
i want to display hello with name which i mentioned in controller, plese guide me i am new in symfony.

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\users;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @Route("/login", name="login")
   */
  public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
    
    if($request->getMethod()=='POST'){
      $username=$request->get('username');
      $password=$request->get('password');
      $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
      $repository=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:users');
      $user=$repository->findOneBy(array('userName'=>$username, 'password'=>$password)); 
    
      if($user)
      {
          return $this->render('default/login.html.twig', array('name' =>$user->getFirstName()));
      }
    }
    else{
      return $this->render('default/login.html.twig');
    }
  }
}
```

**login.html.twig**

This is my login page in symfony,  want to display hello with name which i mentioned in **Hello {{name}}** this line, please do some correction if needed.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    {% block stylesheets %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('templates/css/1.css') }}">
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>  
    
    {% block container %}
    
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login User</h2>                    
        <form class="form-sigin" method="POST" action="{{path('login')}}">
          <div><input type="text" name="user_name" class="txtbox" placeholder="User Name"></div>
          <div><input type="password" name="password" class="txtbox" placeholder="Password"></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox"><span>Remember</span></div>
          <div><input type="submit" value="Log In" class="loginBtn"></div>
          <div><span><a href="">Forgot Password</a></span></div>
        </form>
      </div>
      {% if name is defined  %}
        <div class="alert-info fade in">
          <strong>Hello {{name}}</strong>
        </div>
      {% endif  %}

    {% endblock %}  
  </body>
</html>
```

**users.php**

```php
<?php
    
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
    
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    
/**
 * users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\usersRepository")
 */
class users
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $userName;
   
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;
    
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;
    
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    
    /**
     * Set userName
     *
     * @param string $userName
     *
     * @return users
     */
    public function setUserName($userName)
    {
        $this->userName = $userName;
  
        return $this;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get userName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->userName;
    }
    
    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     *
     * @return users
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }
  
    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return users
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    
        return $this;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a bad indentation to see the problem.. try this:

```
     if($request->getMethod()=='POST')
     {
        $username=$request->get('username');
        $password=$request->get('password');

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $repository=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:users');
        $user=$repository->findOneBy(array('userName'=>$username, 'password'=>$password)); 

        if($user)
        {
            return $this->render('default/login.html.twig', array('name' =>$user->getFirstName()));
        } else {
            return $this->render('default/login.html.twig');
        }
    } else{
        return $this->render('default/login.html.twig');
    }
```

The problem was that you are inside POST request but there ins't user, so It doesn't enter inside any return.

I have added a new condition `else` to return in this case.

I don't know if the logic is correct for you, but the problem  was that

Comment: Thanks sir my problem is solved, but my task is not complete  can you assist me further on my task.

Comment: It depends on what. For new task you can open a new question for example :) If this answer solved your problem accept It when you can to help other guys with your same problem please @KumarPal

Comment: Sir like using session and after submit button my page will be redirect to dashboard page.

Comment: How can I redirect to dashboard page after submit button.

Comment: Uhm, try please to open a new question with your code and I'll try to answer  @KumarPal

Comment: Sir if i will open a new question website show You have reached your question limit and it will take 2 days.